# How to generate OptimistickLockException by parallel transactions?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb

I know multiple causes can trigger `OptimistickLockException`, but current test case demands a two transactions write into same data at same time to trigger the exception. More like to create read/write violation issue by parallel transactions. This is what I did:

1. In the testing class, Create a private field to hold the transactions and some transactional methods:

   ```
   private List<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<Transaction>();

   // This method only generate transactions and assign
   // them to the member field
   @Transactional 
   public void retrieveTransactions(){
       transactions = generateTransactions(); // generateTransactions() is transactional
   }

   // Following two methods just write those
   // transactions into same summery, only the first one sleeps
   // during the process to make sure the second transaction
   // can occur in a parallel way
   @Transactional
   public void processTransactionsOne(){
       for(Transaction transaction:transactions){
           logger.info("====Transaction One=====");
           transaction.writeToSameSummary(); // writeToSameSummary() is transactional
           try {Thread.sleep(10000); } // sleep for 10 seconds before commit
           catch(InterruptedException ex) {}
       }
   }
   @Transactional
   public void processTransactionsTwo(){
       for(Transaction transaction:transactions){
           logger.info("====Transaction Two=====");
           transaction.writeToSameSummary(); // writeToSameSummary() is transactional
       }
   }
   ```
2. in `applicationContext.xml`, I have made above three methods as scheduler, `retrieveTransactions` run every 60 seconds, `processTransactionsOne` and `processTransactionsTwo` run every 10 seconds

   ```
   <task:scheduled ref="testBeanName" method="retrieveTransactions" cron="*/60 * * * * *"/>
   <task:scheduled ref="testBeanName" method="processTransactionsOne" cron="*/10 * * * * *"/>
   <task:scheduled ref="testBeanName" method="processTransactionsTwo" cron="*/10 * * * * *"/>
   ```

However, I can never reproduce `OptimistickLockException` and the log showing up

```
====Transaction One=====
====Transaction One=====
====Transaction One=====
......
====Transaction Two=====
====Transaction Two=====
====Transaction Two=====
```

So the transaction are running as synchronized and never in parallel. So how can I (1) making `parallel transactions` and (2)reproduce `OptimistickLockException`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reproduce the optimistic locking exception, try to run code from a method that is not itself transactional. For example call a method that reads and modifies an entity, and returns a detached copy.

Then call the same method to modify the same entity, and return a new detached copy. The first copy now is stale compared to the database. Try to merge the first stale copy into a session, it will throw the optimistic locking exception.

This is some sample code for a versioned entity:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
   ...
   @Version
   private Long version;
}
```

and this an example of a service that reads and returns an entity detached:

```
@Repository
public class SomeRepository {
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    @Transactional
    public MyEntity readAndModify(Long key) {
        MyEntity myEntity = em.find( key, MyEntity.class);
        myEntity.setSomeField(...); // this will trigger update via dirty checking
        return myEntity;
    }
}
```

This code in a test can then trigger the optimistic locking exception:

```
public someNonTransactionalTest() {
    //read and modify entity, get detached copy
    MyEntity detachedCopy1 = someRepository.readAndModify(1L); 

    //read and modify entity, get another detached copy - copy 1 is stale now
    MyEntity detachedCopy2 = someRepository.readAndModify(1L); 

    // try to merge the stale copy to a session, the optimistic locking exception is thrown
    detachedCopy1 = entityManager.merge(detachedCopy1);

    ... assertions ...
}
```